# Acts as Votable Prompt on Downvote Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, vote

I am using acts_as_votable on my rails 4 app.

I have it set up so upvotes/downvotes are take via an ajax request. I would like to implement a prompt, or a confirmation with a text box inside of it, so when a user downvotes an article a popup is displayed and they can input their reason for downvoting it.

I am having trouble finding any sort of documentation on doing so. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Here is my current controller code:

```
  def upvote 
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @subarticle = @article.subarticles.find(params[:id])
    session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
    voter = Session.find_or_create_by(ip: session[:voting_id])
    voter.likes @subarticle
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @subarticle.get_upvotes.size } }
    end
  end

  def downvote
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @subarticle = @article.subarticles.find(params[:id])
    session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
    voter = Session.find_or_create_by(ip: session[:voting_id])
    voter.dislikes @subarticle
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.json { render json: { count: @subarticle.get_downvotes.size } }
    end
  end
```

and inside of the view:

```
        <%= link_to like_article_subarticle_path(@article, @subarticle), class: "voteup", method: :put, remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-right:5px">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Helpful
        </button><div class="badge" style="margin-right:10px"><%= @subarticle.get_upvotes.size %></div>
        <% end %>

        <script>
            $('.voteup')
          .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
          .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
          .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
          .on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).find("div").text("+1"); });
        </script>

        <%= link_to dislike_article_subarticle_path(@article, @subarticle), class: "votedown", method: :put, remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-right:5px">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Unhelpful
        </button><div class="badge"><%= @subarticle.get_downvotes.size %></div>
        <% end %>

        <script>
            $('.votedown')
          .on('ajax:send', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
          .on('ajax:complete', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
          .on('ajax:error', function () { $(this).after('<div class="error">There was an issue.</div>'); })
          .on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) { $(this).find("div").text("-1"); });
        </script>
```

Thank you for any help. Been trying to find a way to do this for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want it as a ***pop-up***, your best bet would be triggering a ***modal*** upon clicking the `link_to`

```
<%= link_to dislike_article_subarticle_path(@article, @subarticle), class: "votedown", method: :put, remote: true, data: { type: :json, toggle: "modal", target: "#my-modal" } do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" aria-label="Left Align" style="margin-right:5px">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
       Unhelpful
    </button>
    <div class="badge"><%= @subarticle.get_downvotes.size %></div>
<% end %>
```

And include a ***form*** containing a `text_field/text_area` for the user to include a reason for downvoting.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="my-modal" title="My modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Modal Body
    #your form goes here
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button aria-hidden="true" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't like the approach, you can also use ***fadeIn/fadeOut*** or ***hide/show*** to display the ***form*** containing a `text_field/text_area` but you won't get that ***pop-up*** effect with those.